# python button change text after click

Tags: python, button, tkinter, widget

i want to make a Button that changes the displayed text(number) after every click and returns the valure defined in the function, because i want to work with the displayed variables.

I created a function that adds +1 to "text" after every click until 4
and a button. The code does not return the valure of the function and the button has only the text = 1,2,3 or 4.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

text = 0
def text_change():
    global text
    text += 1

    print(text)
    if text >= 4:
        text = 0

#to change: button text has to be the variable defined in the function
btn = tk.Button(text = "1,2,3 or 4", width = 10, height = 3, command = \
                text_change).grid(row = 1 , column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: Clicked Button can't return value.

Comment: btw: `btn = tk.Button(...).grid(..)` always assigns `None` to `btn`. Use use `btn = tk.Button(...) ; btn.grid(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First

```
btn = tk.Button(...).grid(..)
```

assigns `None` to `btn` because `grid()` returns `None`

use

```
btn = tk.Button(...)
btn.grid(...)
```

Now you can change text on button using `btn['text'] = "new text"` or `btn.config(text="new text")`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def text_change():
    global text

    text += 1

    if text > 4:
        text = 1

    print("changed to:", text)

    #btn['text'] = text
    btn.config(text=text)

def text_print():
    print("current:", text)

# --- main ---

text = 0

root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(text="1,2,3 or 4", command=text_change, width=10, height=3)
btn.grid(row=1, column=1)

btn2 = tk.Button(text="SHOW", command=text_print, width=10, height=3)
btn2.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you! Do you know how to assigne the 1,2,3 or 4 to a variable ? So i can work with the variables

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You already have `text` variable and you can work with it.

Comment: yea but i think the text value in "text_change()" is local, so the text = 0 ist always 0. And i want to overwrite the text = 0 with the text-value of "text_change()"

Comment: as an example my code : `a = text if a == 1:  print("kkk")` doesnt work

Comment: `text` is not local because I used `global text`

Comment: Where did you use `a=text ; if a==1 : print("kkk")` ? Maybe you use it when `text` still is `0`

Comment: I changed code in my answer. Now there is second button to print current `text`.

Comment: ahh now i understand, the text outside the function changes the text variable to 0. Thanks!!!!